# How to send send an array of objects to a NamedQuery that needs the "id" of all the objects.

Tags: java, arrays, jpa

I am building a report from information received from a muti-select form element in a jsp page.

In my repository class I am getting an array of objects from that element. I need to call the `getId` function for each one of these objects and send those ids to the `NamedQuery`.

Here is a code example to help explain. I know how to handle a single object but with an array of objects I get lost at the `.setParameter(1, employees[].getId())` part.

```
    public List<RequestByRequester> getFormInformation(
        Employee[] employees) 
        throws NoDataFoundException {

        List<RequestByRequester> resultList = getEm().createNamedQuery(
                "requestByRequestor.getRequestsByRequesters", RequestByRequester.class)
                .setParameter(1, employees[].getId())
                .getResultList();

        return resultList;
    }
```

By request the query:

```
    SELECT EMP.EMPL_FIRST_NAME || ' ' || EMP.EMPL_LAST_NAME REQUESTER,
           R.RQST_ID RQST_ID,
           R.TITLE TITLE,
           R.DESCRIPTION DESCR,
           DECODE(R.RESOLUTION_DATE, NULL, 'Open', 'Closed') STAT
   FROM TARTS.REQUESTS R, SYS_EMPLOYEES EMP
  WHERE R.EMPL_ID_REQUESTED_BY = EMP.EMPL_ID
    AND EMP.EMPL_ID IN (?)
  ORDER BY 1, 5 DESC, 2
```

Comment: What does "namedQueries.queryName" look like?  Perhaps you can do an "in" and give it a list of IDs?

Comment: This question is really a JPA question and not a Spring question, no?

Comment: @bkent314 I can put the actual query name an string up. I was just trying to make it less confusing, but it seems I accomplished the opposite. I am very new to java/jpa/spring thought it was spring related question. Sorry ^_^

Comment: No Problem!  More info, the better.  Bohemian has a great answer for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried calling Madame Mystique to get help with finding out what your query actually was, but no luck, so I'm just going to go for it...

Your named query should look something like this:

```
select x
from MyClass x
where x.children.id in (:ids)
```

then get your ids into a list

```
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ids.add(someid);  // etc
```

then use this to specify it in your query

```
.setParameter("ids", ids)
```

Comment: I think I understand. I was considering doing something like this but doing a for each through the employee array appending the ID to a string and sending that string as a param. Yours is much cleaner. Thank you!

Comment: I know this is old, but I don't understand how the `x.children.id` works. Would something like this work too: `SELECT * FROM myClass WHERE myClass.theColumn NOT IN (:listOfNumbersToExclude)` ? Thanks!

Comment: @shanehoban in HQL `x.children.id` does the join for you. `children` maps to `getChildren()`, which returns a Set of entities that have a foreign key reference to `x`. The whole HQL query is equivalent to `select x.* from MyTable x join ChildTable c on c.myTableId = x.id where c.id in (:ids)`. The foreign key info is defined in the `@ManyToOne` annotation on the child class's `getMyClassId()` method. Yes `not in (:ids)` works too. btw, in native HQL all referenced tables must have an alias, so `SELECT t FROM myClass t where ...` and `select` is optional, so `FROM myClass t where...` works too