# invalid column type ~ Sending ArrayList<String> to a pl/sql createdNameQuery

Tags: java, jpa, plsql

This is related to a past [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879270/how-to-send-send-an-array-of-objects-to-a-namedquery-that-needs-the-id-of-all-t) of mine.

I am receiving a `List<Employee>` and grabbing the ids from the `Employee` objects and putting them in an `ArrayList<String>` then sending that `ArrayList` as a parameter in the `createdNameQuery`. I am receiving an invalid column type sql exception. I tested the query in pl/sql developer and it returned fields. I have tried building out a string of ids by placing a coma between each id and sending that but, I received an exception from that attempt. I am curious if I have the query setup incorrectly or sending the data incorrectly.

function in my repository:

```
public List<RequestByRequester> getRequestsByRequesters(
        List<Employee> employeeList) 
        throws NoDataFoundException {

    List<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Employee emp : employeeList) {          
        idList.add(emp.getId().toString());
    }

    log.debug("Input params[requesters=" + idList + "]");

    List<RequestByRequester> resultList = getEm().createNamedQuery(
            "requestByRequestor.getRequestsByRequesters", RequestByRequester.class)
            .setParameter(1,idList)
            .getResultList();

        if(resultList == null || resultList.size() <= 0)
            throw new NoDataFoundException("No requests found by requesters.");
        else
            return resultList;
}
```

My named query **requestByRequestor.getRequestsByRequesters** below:

```
   @NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "requestByRequestor.getRequestsByRequesters",
    resultClass = RequestByRequester.class,
    query = "SELECT EMP.EMPL_FIRST_NAME || ' ' || EMP.EMPL_LAST_NAME REQUESTER," +
            "       R.RQST_ID RQST_ID," +
            "       R.TITLE TITLE," +
            "       R.DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION," +
            "       DECODE(R.RESOLUTION_DATE, NULL, 'Open', 'Closed') STATUS" +
            "  FROM TARTS.REQUESTS R, SYS_EMPLOYEES EMP" +
            " WHERE R.EMPL_ID_REQUESTED_BY = EMP.EMPL_ID" +
            "   AND EMP.EMPL_ID IN (?)" +
            " ORDER BY 1, 5 DESC, 2"
    )
```

EDIT: Adding exceptions as requested.

This exception when I use `:ids` in the query:

`Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
Error Code: 17041
Call: SELECT EMP.EMPL_FIRST_NAME || ' ' || EMP.EMPL_LAST_NAME REQUESTER,       R.RQST_ID RQST_ID,       R.TITLE TITLE,       R.DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION,       DECODE(R.RESOLUTION_DATE, NULL, 'Open', 'Closed') STATUS  FROM TARTS.REQUESTS R, SYS_EMPLOYEES EMP WHERE R.EMPL_ID_REQUESTED_BY = EMP.EMPL_ID   AND EMP.EMPL_ID IN :ids ORDER BY 1, 5 DESC, 2
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="requestByRequestor.getRequestsByRequesters" referenceClass=RequestByRequester sql="SELECT EMP.EMPL_FIRST_NAME || ' ' || EMP.EMPL_LAST_NAME REQUESTER,       R.RQST_ID RQST_ID,       R.TITLE TITLE,       R.DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION,       DECODE(R.RESOLUTION_DATE, NULL, 'Open', 'Closed') STATUS  FROM TARTS.REQUESTS R, SYS_EMPLOYEES EMP WHERE R.EMPL_ID_REQUESTED_BY = EMP.EMPL_ID   AND EMP.EMPL_ID IN :ids ORDER BY 1, 5 DESC, 2")`

Exception when I use `?1` or `(?)` in the query :

`Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
Error Code: 17004
Call: SELECT EMP.EMPL_FIRST_NAME || ' ' || EMP.EMPL_LAST_NAME REQUESTER,       R.RQST_ID RQST_ID,       R.TITLE TITLE,       R.DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION,       DECODE(R.RESOLUTION_DATE, NULL, 'Open', 'Closed') STATUS  FROM TARTS.REQUESTS R, SYS_EMPLOYEES EMP WHERE R.EMPL_ID_REQUESTED_BY = EMP.EMPL_ID   AND EMP.EMPL_ID IN ? ORDER BY 1, 5 DESC, 2
    bind => [[2192, 632]]
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="requestByRequestor.getRequestsByRequesters" referenceClass=RequestByRequester sql="SELECT EMP.EMPL_FIRST_NAME || ' ' || EMP.EMPL_LAST_NAME REQUESTER,       R.RQST_ID RQST_ID,       R.TITLE TITLE,       R.DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION,       DECODE(R.RESOLUTION_DATE, NULL, 'Open', 'Closed') STATUS  FROM TARTS.REQUESTS R, SYS_EMPLOYEES EMP WHERE R.EMPL_ID_REQUESTED_BY = EMP.EMPL_ID   AND EMP.EMPL_ID IN ? ORDER BY 1, 5 DESC, 2")`

Comment: what are those ORDER BY terms supposed to mean? they are not a result_variable, nor are they state_field_path_expression. Suggest a read of the JPA spec section 4.9. If you want to use a result expression in the order by you use an alias "SELECT something AS p" and then can refer to "p" in the order by. If instead you meant this as SQL then you're using the wrong method for query generation

Comment: Please include the named query definition

Comment: @James it is included below the text **requestByRequestor.getRequestsByRequesters**

Comment: Can you post the exception you are seeing?

Comment: I have been able to get this to work by running a for each loop going through the idList running the query on 1 id at a time and setting the results to a tempList and then `.addAll` the tempList to the main resultList. This is not a clean way to do it but a band-aid solution until someone can figure out the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue (I think, because you did not include the definition of your named query), is that you are executing a native SQL query, and a List is not a valid SQL/JDBC parameter value.

EclipseLink support List parameters for JPQL queries, but not for native SQL queries.

You need to either use JPQL, or define each of the parameters in your SQL

i.e.

```
EMP.EMPL_ID IN (:id1, :id2, :id3)

.setParameter("id1", idList.get(0));
.setParameter("id2", idList.get(1));
```

Comment: Like I had mentioned in response to your previous comment. My named query is in my original post. Please look right above the listings of the exceptions. It is right above the line **EDIT: Adding exceptions as requested**

Comment: I think you are right. Going to have to use a JPQL query. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here

```
AND EMP.EMPL_ID IN (?)
```

To indicate positional parameters, you need to suffix the questionmark with the number.

```
 AND EMP.EMPL_ID IN (?1)
```

Alternately, you can do

```
 AND EMP.EMPL_ID IN (:empIds)
```

and then call your query like so

```
List<RequestByRequester> resultList = getEm().createNamedQuery(
        "requestByRequestor.getRequestsByRequesters", RequestByRequester.class)
        .setParameter("empIds", idList)
        .getResultList();
```

Comment: I tried the `AND EMP.EMPL_ID IN (?1)` approach and received the invalid column error. When I tried `AND EMP.EMPL_ID IN (:empIds)` approach I received this `Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index` error.

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
List<RequestByRequester> resultList = getEm().createNamedQuery(
    "requestByRequestor.getRequestsByRequesters", RequestByRequester.class)
    .setParameter("ids", idList)
    .getResultList();
```

NamedQuery WHERE part:

```
WHERE R.EMPL_ID_REQUESTED_BY = EMP.EMPL_ID
AND EMP.EMPL_ID IN :ids
```

Notice the `:ids` is without brackets. This should work.

Comment: I tried it without the brackets and received `Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index`

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are mapping emp.getId() to String

```
List<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Employee emp : employeeList) {          
        idList.add(emp.getId().toString());
    }
```

But I bet the type for this column EMP.EMPL_ID is Numeric or some such thing. When you perform

```
.setParameter("empIds", idList)
```

JPA will be converting that to a string value with quotes and escape chars etc. hence:

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type

try mapping to `List<Long>` or some other numeric type.

Comment: the EMP.EMPL_ID is a Long and I tried the List<Long>, and changed the query around with the previous suggestions and had the same results as before.

Comment: Are you using a SqlResultSetMapping or specifying a ResultClass with your NamedQuery (requestByRequestor.getRequestsByRequesters)?

Comment: It is a specific ResultClass `RequestByRequester`

Comment: Are you using Hibernate, OpenJPA, or some other JPA implementation?